# Output multiple plots to a single pdf in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, pdf, ggplot2

I am having trouble generating a pdf with multiple plots. When I arrange my plots in a for loop it seems it looses the connection to the pdf and produces an empty pdf.

I have a list of lists called p, with `p.length(p) ==2`.
`p[[1]] and p[[2]]` contain ggplots.

########## This works ##########

myPDFPath = "output/countryProfilesIndividual_testI.pdf"
pdf(file=myPDFPath, onefile = TRUE)

```
gridExtra::marrangeGrob(p[[1]], nrow = length(p[[1]]), ncol = 1, top=quote("My Quote"))
gridExtra::marrangeGrob(p[[2]], nrow = length(p[[2]]), ncol = 1, top=quote("My Quote"))

dev.off()
```

--> Here I get two pages with plots as expected.

########## This works NOT ##########

```
myPDFPath = "output/countryProfiles.pdf"
pdf(file=myPDFPath, onefile = TRUE)
for (listIdx in 1:length(p))
{
  gridExtra::marrangeGrob(p[[listIdx]], nrow = length(p[[listIdx]]), ncol = 1, top=quote("MyQuote"))
}
dev.off()
```

--> The file is written, but it is empty

Do curly brackets cause some behaviour that I am not aware of?
Please note, I don't want to create individual pdfs, but bring everything in one pdf together.
I want to arrange the plots dynamically, so all lapply possibilities I found don't help me because e.g. the nrow or top parameters have to be set individually.

Comment: As you are using *ggplot*, it seems that you have run into the problem that it does not work in for-loops. Does wrapping the plot statement into a `print` help? This was suggested here: https://statisticsglobe.com/print-ggplot2-plot-within-for-loop-in-r

Comment: Thanks a ton! That solved it. 

`print(gridExtra::marrangeGrob(p[[listIdx]], nrow = length(p[[listIdx]]), ncol = 1, top=quote("my quote")))`

Sorry, for some reason I couldn't find anything on this before. You helped my a great deal.